# How can I make an image fall off the screen?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this code to allow me to place a random image next to the user's cursor using javascript and styled using CSS. I would like images to fall down off the page after a few seconds, my first thought was to animate position but apparently that's not possible?

How could I achieve this? Here is my javascript and CSS code

Javascript

```
<script>

var myPix = new Array("/img/portfolio/30day.jpg", "/img/portfolio/animationposter.jpg","/img/portfolio/beetle.jpg","/img/portfolio/board.jpg","/img/portfolio/cyanotype.jpg","/img/portfolio/dissent.jpg")
document.addEventListener("click", showCoords);

function showCoords(event)
{

var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * myPix.length);
var yourImage = document.createElement("img");
yourImage.src = myPix[randomNum] ;
yourImage.classList.add("mystyle");
yourImage.style.cssText = " width:360px;height:auto;position:fixed;top:" + event.clientY + "px;left:" + event.clientX + "px;";

document.body.appendChild(yourImage);
}
jQuery.fn.reverse = [].reverse;
</script>
```

CSS

```
.mystyle {
border-radius: 20px;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
z-index: -2;
width: 360px;
height: auto;
position: fixed;


}
```

Comment: my bad yes, at the moment the more the user clicks the more images appear and it can get chaotic, my thinking is the user will click on the screen after a few seconds the image would fall off the screen and disappear, I know I could edit the opacity as an option but if possible I would really like the images to move down (falling off) I have a single vh size page so there's no scrolling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create an images array so you can easily access all your images. Whenever you create an image, push it to the array:

```
var images = [];
function showCoords(event)
{

var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * myPix.length);
var yourImage = document.createElement("img");
yourImage.src = myPix[randomNum] ;
yourImage.classList.add("mystyle");
yourImage.style.cssText = " width:360px;height:auto;position:fixed;top:" + event.clientY + "px;left:" + event.clientX + "px;";
images.push([yourImage,0,0]); // this line is where we add the image. 
//In the same sub-array, put a number, 0, to store the image's age, and a velocity, 0, to make the physics look good. These will be used later.
document.body.appendChild(yourImage);
}
```

In order to animate your images, you need to set up some kind of animate loop and call it in a `setInterval`:

```
animate = function(){}
setInterval(animate,5); // choose whatever interval you want. Here, it is called every 5 milliseconds
```

Inside the animate function, we need to add the logic to change every image's position:

```
animate = function(){
   for(image of images){ // loop over all elements of our array
      image[1] += 1; //increase the age
      if(image[1] > 400){ //if old enough, fall
         image[2] += 0.1; //accelerate, tweak this value to change how strong gravity is
         currentTop = parseFloat(image[0].style.top.replace("px","")); // get the current y position
         currentTop += image[2]; //move
         newTop = String(currentTop) + "px"; //change back to string
         image[0].style.top = newTop; //set the attribute

         if(newTop > document.documentElement.clientHeight){ //if off-screen, remove it
         document.body.removeChild(image[0]);
         images.splice(images.indexOf(image),1); //remove from array
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Now you should be good to go. I tested this out in Chrome and it worked for the simple case where I just had one image on screen; hopefully I haven't made any typos writing it up here. To change the speed, either change the acceleration value or change the time in the setInterval. Hope this helps!

Edit: [here](https://jsfiddle.net/xcvdnL3h/1/) is a working jsFiddle. I had to use spans instead of images because I don't have your exact image files, but everything else is the same.

Comment: Firstyl I do want to thank you for spending time replying I have copied the code word for word and got no errors (using visual studio code), however nothing functions images don't even show when clicking

When I remove the line images.push([yourImage,0,0]) everything fixes itself and the normal click to show image works but no falling animation

Comment: Hmm - that's strange if there were no errors. The only thing I can think of is maybe that it's because I forgot a semi-colon after that line?

Comment: Edited and added the semi-colon in. Maybe that was the problem?

Comment: animation works perfectly the only issue is instead of images its just text or the location? so its identical to the jsFiddle which I expected on jsFiddle as it can't access my images but I've gone through the code and can't seem to find the issue? I know the images are in the same location as my original code works when I switch back and forth.

Comment: update I managed to figure it out no idea how just messing with the code and it worked thank you so much for your time and effort

Comment: Great! Glad you got it working. I deliberately made it only text in the fiddle just as an example because I didn't want to upload actual images.